# Creating aspect for multiple plugins in eclipse RCP project

Tags: logging, aspectj, ajdt

I am developing a rcp project having multiple plugins and i am using AJDT aspectJ for logging purpose in the application. I have created two aspects one for info logging and one for exception logging in each plugin.Aspect is working fine for base plugin but it is not working for other plugin.

I am having few queries regarding above implementation:

1. is this a correct way to define a aspect for each plugin or can we create one aspect for all plugins
2. if the package name are same in different plugins is it a problem while creating seprate aspect for each plugin.
3. I tried to create one aspect for normal logging and exception logging but not working for me. Attaching sample for normal aspect and exception aspect.
4. Is there any way to define a aspect without providing package name, i think as i am mentioning the package name in pointcut it is creating problem.

I am getting below error if having one aspect in each plugin:

```
Caused by: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: com_tsystems_rvs_client_gui_user_RvsUserAspect
at com.tsystems.rvs.client.gui.user.RvsUserAspect.aspectOf(RvsUserAspect.aj:1)
at com.tsystems.rvs.client.gui.user.RvsUserAspect.<clinit>(RvsUserAspect.aj:27)
```

Code for normal aspect used to log info msg

```
public aspect RvsFrameworkAspect {


public pointcut scope(): within(com.tsystems.rvs.client.gui.framework.*);

before() : scope(){
    Signature sig=thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    String infoFormat="Entering ["+sig.getDeclaringType().getName()+"."+sig.getName();
    logTrace(infoFormat, thisJoinPointStaticPart, thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
}

after() : scope(){
    Signature sig=thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    String infoFormat="Leaving ["+sig.getDeclaringType().getName()+"."+sig.getName()+"]";
    logTrace(infoFormat, thisJoinPointStaticPart, thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
}
protected synchronized void logTrace(String info, StaticPart location,
        StaticPart enclosing) {

        Signature signature = location.getSignature();

        String source = signature.getDeclaringTypeName() + ":" + 
            (enclosing.getSourceLocation().getLine());
       LoggerMode.getInstance().logInfo(" " + source + " - " + info);


}

}
```

Code for log exceptions in plugin

```
public aspect RvsFrameworkExceptionAspect {

public pointcut scope(): within(com.tsystems.rvs..*);
private Map<Throwable, String> loggedThrowables = new WeakHashMap<Throwable, String>();

after() throwing(Throwable t): scope() {

    logThrowable(t, thisJoinPointStaticPart, 
            thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
    }

before (Throwable t): handler(Exception+) && args(t) && scope() {

    logThrowable(t, thisJoinPointStaticPart, 
            thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
    }
protected synchronized void logThrowable(Throwable t, StaticPart location,
        StaticPart enclosing) {

    if (!loggedThrowables.containsKey(t)) {
        loggedThrowables.put(t, null);

        Signature signature = location.getSignature();

        String source = signature.getDeclaringTypeName() + ":"
                + (enclosing.getSourceLocation().getLine());


            LoggerMode.getInstance().logError(" " + source + " - " + t.toString(), t);

    }
}
```

}

Please help me what i am doing wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your pointcut in `RvsFrameworkExceptionAspect` is just advising classes you want to exclude. Specifically,

`within(com.tsystems.rvs..*)`

will match

`com.tsystems.rvs.client.gui.user.RvsUserAspect`,

i.e. you are advising another aspect, as it seems. Try to be a little more specific about what you want to intercept.

---

**Edit** concerning your additional question in the comment:

You can try this if your aspects all have class names ending with "Aspect":

`within(com.tsystems.rvs..*) && !within(*..*Aspect)`

Otherwise you can exclude single aspect classes or just include fewer non-aspect classes, whatever is simpler in your case. Generally, it is hard to provide helpful hints without knowing your full code base, so please understand I that might not hit the target as exactly as you might wish. ;-)

Comment: can you please guide me with some example.